# select string literal in cassandra cql

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to Cassandra and I am trying to run a simple query in CQL:

```
select aggregate_name as name, 'test' as test from aggregates;
```

and I get an error: **Line 1: no viable alternative at input ''test''**

The question is: how could I select string literal in Apache Cassandra?

Comment: [adding this as a comment as I'm not 100% sure] I don't think CQL supports that, probably the closest you can get to that is by creating an UDF...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an ugly workaround, if you really want to print a text value as a column:

```sql
cqlsh> select aggregate_name as name, blobAsText(textAsBlob('test')) as test from aggregates;
 name | test
------+------
 dude | test
```

CQL supports native Cassandra functions as a `select_expression`, so you can convert your string literal *to a blob and back again* as shown above. ([source](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__select-expression))

Comment: Nice!  You're right that it's definitely ugly, but I kind of like that workaround.